# Storing mysql database connection safe?

Tags: java

I couldn't really find an answer for this. Maybe because the answer is obvious. Anyway, is it safe to store a password in a runnable jar?

Like, I'm making a database connection in a class. Are people able to read this code? I don't want them to know the MySQL passwords.

Comment: Define "safe". Also what alternative are you considering? You could encrypt them and store them in a properties file.

Comment: Unless encrypted (with a password that is not stored in the same place), no data in a file which you allow others to access is "safe".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not safe.  The general rule of thumb is that anything you put in a client is out of your control.  Once its on their computer, they can do anything they want to it, including disassemble, run `strings` on it, rewrite portions of it (to cheat in games, for example), build a completely separate app with the information they've cleaned from yours about how it interacts with your services, etc.

If you're writing a client/server app, the client should connect to a service, and the service should connect to the database.  If you're concerned about people accessing the database, you probably also will want to implement a login for your service.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what do you mean by service? Everyone is allowed to use it without an account, I only want to insert a row into a database safely.

Comment: By service I mean some kind of server-side functionality that you control yourself.  

I assume this database is shared, since you have concerns about password sharing, so the service would be (for example) a web application (asp, php, java, etc) that the client interacts with, and then the web application would interact with the database.  It would also be up to the web application to validate any inputs from the client to ensure the client isn't attempting anything malicious or undefined.

Comment: Also worth noting: there is a general lack of context, so I am just guessing as to what you're trying to do.  In general, its considered bad practice to open your database connection to the public for any reason; they're generally not designed for that.  Putting a service in front for validation and security is the expected practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, never hard code your passwords, try to use encryption and or environment variables instead.

I like jasypt (http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html), take a look it and I hope this helps you.

Comment: @user2879055 , if you find it interesting would you please vote it up please.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't before due to not enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Decompiling a JAR file is exceptionally easy. In my opinion and based on my experiences, you should **never** leave your MySQL database information just sitting inside of the JAR file. Instead, you should **always** make a connection to some backend listener on your server (*for example, a PHP script*) that sanitizes all input before it is used to access the database. Your backend listener can then return the result of the database query to your application.

The only time it is acceptable to do SQL database queries on the client-side is when you have the client accessing a locally stored database that only contains data relevant to them/their runtime. In my experience, though, those cases are few and far between, so in general, you should never do client-side database connections. Always delegate those connections to a server-side API.